# Android- DynamoDB authenticater user

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I've been developing Android app which is connected to AWS. I save data in DynamoDB in app.

I configured DynamoDB that only user with the right ID can write or update his record. In all SDK sampples, the way to invoke DynamoDB is using this way:

```
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentials = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            context,
            Constants.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
            Regions.US_EAST_1);

    ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
```

I would expect it to include username and password or sessionToken which identify 
the user.

The above doesn't contain any information on the user but on the region. How can I specify the user who is requesting the opertaion?

Thanks,

Comment: I would look at all the different `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` constructors in the docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.html There are some that take `accounttId` which I believe is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I Managed to do it. For those who wants to know how to do it:
1. Create CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider() object

```
 CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    identityPoolId,
                    Regions.US_EAST_1);
```

You will than need to create map:

```
Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
logins.put(developerName, JWTToken);
```

developerName is the developer ID.
than call

```
credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
credentialsProvider.refresh();
AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
                               mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddb);

DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
```

You must set the authentication and unauthenticated policy.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

The account id is not the user's account but the developer accountid.